# How can I modify anonymous type items in a List?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var anonymous = list.Select(item => new List{name,age}).ToList();
anonymous.ForEach(item=> item.age=20);
```

**ForEach is not working with anonymous types.**

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (`new List{name,age}` does not create an instance of an anonymous object, it doesn't even compile) and show what you have tried. You cannot modify properties of anonymous objects. Your problem description is also off. ForEach definitely works with anonymous types, the problem is not your ForEach call. Instead of claiming it's "not working", read and research the error message.

Comment: `ForEach` is a List method, not LINQ. LINQ is a query language, it doesn't modify data

Comment: If you want to modify values use a tuple instead of an anonymous type

Comment: Can the user who upvoted this please explain why they did that?

Comment: Another possibility is to *not* modify the values at all. Return instances with the new value. Either specify the required value in the original `Select` or use `Select(item=>new {item.name,20})` to produce copies with the new values

Comment: @Jay why did you add that irrelevant code?

Comment: How is it not relevant I used it in production to help do exactly that which was asked.

Comment: @Jay you maybe edited another post than you think you were editing.

Comment: No my type has a setter ONLY for Type of the given... it needs another struct to be truly non boxing Invariant<T> but I didn't include that. its homewerk. It still answers the question without it...

```
 var invariant = new Variants.Invariant();

            invariant.Object = new object();
invariant.Type =  typeof(int);

Comment: @Jay I have no idea what you're talking about, but anyway, don't edit (partial) answers into questions, that's not how this site works.

Comment: @CodeCaster Can I add the complete answer? The post is closed and I like the question

Comment: @Jay it's a duplicate of at least two, probably many more questions. If you think you have code that answers the question "how to modify properties of an anonymous object", then go post a (complete!) answer to any of those.

Comment: Modify properties are not the same thing as chaining the type per type. If the type definitely has the properties but cannot be proven statically etc its for sure safe.

Comment: @Jay perhaps try to explain yourself more accurately. I have no idea what you mean by "chaining the type per type", but if you think you have an answer to a popular question, go find a question and post your answer, or post a self-answered question.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! @CodeCaster

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of **read-only** properties into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first.

So you can't modify instance of anonymous type.

As for iterating through collection on anonymous types it should be easily achieved with `foreach`:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
    .Select(i => new {age = i, name = ""})
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.age);
}
```